# VSCode/GoLint: Error for glide/vendor packages

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, lint

I am using VS Code and its giving me linter errors when importing pacakges from vendor folder (glide installed packages). How can I resolve this? `go run` works, so theres nothing wrong with the import

[image]

*Notice error importing chi*

Comment: Try running go imports (For whatever reason some of the go "linters" get fussy about the order of your import statements)